# Substitute strings into {plm} model

Tags: r, regression, plm

[This tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/looping_strings.htm) shows how to substitute strings into an `lm` model call. I want to do the same thing but using `plm` for panel regression. The goal is to make a grid of parameter combinations and then run several regressions with one `apply` call, substituting in the appropriate variables each time.

```
library(plm)    
#make grid of parameters to loop over; select just the first row to reproduce the error
parameters <- expand.grid(dv="mpg", x1=c("cyl", "gear"), x2=c("hp", "wt"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
row <- parameters[1,]

#lm works
lm(substitute(y ~ x*z, list(y=as.name(row[[1]]), x=as.name(row[[2]]), z=as.name(row[[3]]))), data=mtcars)

#plm does not
plm(substitute(y ~ x*z, list(y=as.name(row[[1]]), x=as.name(row[[2]]), z=as.name(row[[3]]))), data=mtcars)
```

This yields:

> Error: inherits(object, "formula") is not TRUE

A solution could involve pasting the variable names into `plm` some other way than using `substitute`. Or can I avoid using `plm` for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plm requires panel data.
You could use the `Produc` example dataset from `?plm`.

```
library(plm)
parameters <- expand.grid(dv="pcap", 
                          x1=c("hwy", "water"), 
                          x2=c("util", "pc"), 
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
row <- parameters[1,]

# I assign the formula to another object
# to avoid clutter in calling plm()
formula.plm <- substitute(y ~ x  * z, 
                   list(y = as.name(row[[1]]), 
                        x = as.name(row[[2]]), 
                        z = as.name(row[[3]]))) 

plm(eval(formula.plm), data = Produc)
```

Comment: I was generating the same error with panel data, but your code works on my data. The difference seems to be the inclusion of `eval`. Thanks!